# Let N be a natural number and 1= d1<d2<..<d{s-1}<d{s}=N its divisors. We calculate the greatest common divisors. for (d1,d2), (d2, d3),...(d{s-1},d{s.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $N$ be a natural number and $1=d_1<d_2<..<d_{s} = N$ its divisors. We calculate the greatest Common divisors for $(d_1, d_2), (d_2,d_3),...(d_{s-1},d_{s})$. Find all $N$ for what the sum of all this greatest Common divisors is $N-2$.
For $N$ prime number, the online solution is 3. Also,I noticed that the greatest common divisor of $(d_1,d_2)=1$ and the greatest common divisor of $(d_{s-1}, d_{s})$ is $d_{s-1}$. How can I go on? I absolut verifica that, if $N$ is a prime power with both the Base and the exponent greater or equal with 2, there are no solutions.

Comment: If N îs a prime power with both the base and the exponent greater ot equal than 2, it does not work. I verified

Comment: Worth adding that to your post!

Comment: I did not find any composite numbers that work so far..

Comment: Yes, my "example" was a numerical blunder.  I'd conduct a search as far as you can.  If no examples other than $3$ show up, maybe that's the only one?  At least it gives you some particular thing to think about.

Comment: I note that getting $N-1$ seems easy enough, so it's funny that $N-2$ is so hard.

Comment: How did you do for N-1?

Comment: It is very likely that 3 is the only solution.

Comment: Well, $6$ works for $N-1$  As the divisors are $1,2,3,6$ so the gcd sequence is $1,1,3$ which sums to $5$.  $12, 24$ both as well.  As does $2^n$ for any $n$. I am beginning to agree with the claim that $3$ is the only example for $N-2$.  Worth trying to prove that, in any case.

Comment: I am thinking..I don't know to prove that, for now.

Comment: This is [A136180](https://oeis.org/A136180).  Not sure that will help, but at least it's a long list of values.

Comment: I Really don't know how to prove that 3 is the only solution..